# Nginx proxy configuration error: [crit] pread()

Tags: nginx, debian, node.js

I'm trying to put my node.js project into my vps. I've watched watch a video which explain how to do that. The problem appened when in create a upstream. Indeed, when I executed the `sudo nginx -t` to see if all is good, I get an error:

```
nginx: [crit] pread() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pol.tf" failed (21: Is a directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

The thing that I don't uderstand is I change nothing in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and it seems the error came from there.

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the tutorial. Indeed, I've put my nodejs file in a wrong folder so I follow another tutorial which is better [Host multiple node.js Applications on a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab)